# QXmlStreamWriter crashes when I try to write too many items

Tags: qt, streamwriter

I am using QXmlStreamWriter to create an xml file with many items. At one point because there are too many elements probably I experience a crash. 
Is there a way to perform a flush on the stream? 
How else can I perform the writing so I do not experience a crash?

Comment: Are you sure you crash is due to the fact that you are writing too many things inside your QXmlStreamWriter? please provide  the piece of code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that QByteArray doesn't support more than 2GB. That's why i had a crash. I used QXmlStreamWriter together with a QByteArray.
If I provide the file directly it works fine.

previous code:

```
QByteArray buffer;
QXmlStreamWriter stream(&buffer);
```

current code:

```
QFile* destFile
QXmlStreamWriter stream(destFile);
```